# My external javascript JQUERY doesn't work on chrome or other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

The html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My Website /title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet4.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'>
</head>
<body>
<!--other code -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my script3.js file is

```
$(function(){

  "use strict";
    $('#checkOut').click(function(){
        var time=2;
         alert("The time is "+time+"!");
    // more code 
});
```

how am I linking it wrong?
when i used jfiddle to test my code, the alert works when i click the button. however, i'm using notepad++ and i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Is your js file in the same folder as your page as you have no path specified?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues, and something else you should fix.

In the script3.js, you have a missing `});`. So it should be:

```
$(function(){
  "use strict";
    $('#checkOut').click(function(){
        var time=2;
        alert("The time is "+time+"!");
        // more code 
    });
});
```

The title tag is not formatted correctly:

```
<title>My Website /title>
```

Needs to be:

```
<title>My Website </title>
```

**EDIT:** Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>My Website </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet4.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--other code -->
        <input type="button" id="checkOut" value="check out" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Putting scripts at the end of the `<body>` is preferred when possible.

Comment: @Pointy putting script at the end, make sense only if there are images in a page.

Comment: @jcubic no, it makes sense for most pages.  It really has nothing to do with images.

Comment: @Pointy putting script at the end make page load faster because script block loading of images and other resources before `<script>` tag. This is the only reason to put script at the end.